# How to call function DB outside view or controller in LARAVEL 4.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I will make subdomain such as Blog by used Wildcard.

but now I use htaccess mod rewrite for call file.php.

I can't use function DB outside view blade. but I want to use function DB in this case. How to I fix this. Thank you so much.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.oranic.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).oranic.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mod.blade.php?sub_name=%1

Comment: there is no context to what you are saying. are you using laravel, are these just random php files?

Comment: i will try to explain that how to use function DB of laravel in root directory.